# Adb can't find my device

Tags: android, device, adb, device-driver

I was developing an android application from Eclipse, connecting my Acer ICONIATAB A 500, with Android 3.0.1. And I did not have any problem.

Now I'm trying to developing the same application on Acer ICONIATAB A 501, with Android 3.2
and my ADB can't find the new device, while Windows can find it! I set in my tablet Debug USB option active, and I installed the appropriate driver on Windows.
I installed even the last Google USB driver (Rev. 7)

I tried to list the device find form adb with command

```
 adb devices
```

from command line, but List of devices attached is empty.

What can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

execute these line

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

if it is mobile device check that in settings, developers options ,  debugging mode is checked or not

Comment: if still not found restart both system and device. finally may be your  cable or usb fault check once

Comment: and had u given the sdk path to adb

Comment: Yes. With another device I have no problem.

Comment: after two days of attempts my device is find from adb :) the problem is that I don't know exactly way! From device manager I update my device driver and I killed and restart adb as suggested from @Sandy09. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `LGUnitedMobileDriver` package from the LG website, even though Windows 7 automatically installed USB drivers for the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your Android-SDK on your computer (in Eclipse or whatever IDE you are using), this helped me solve a similar Problem.